# Have ion-card on top of ion-slide - Ionic 5

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

how to make the ion card float on the ion slider with mobile content, when i move the content it scrolls up with everything.

```
<ion-slide>
<ion-row >
      <div>
      <ion-card mode="md">
        <ion-item class="select-paciente" lines="none">
          <ion-button size="default" slot="star">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
          <h6 style="color: #073f15;">SERVICE</h6>
          <ion-button size="default" slot="end">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-card> 
    </div>     
    </ion-row>     
    <ion-row id="Services">     
      <ion-col size-lg="1" size-md="2" size-sm="3" size-xs="4">
        <ion-card mode="md">
          <img  src="../../../assets/img.jpg" />
          <p>Service1</p>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      </ion-row>  </ion-slide>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this with CSS? position:absolute; top:0;left:0 on ion-card

Comment: Just to clearify, do you want the "not scrollable ion-card" stickied to the top at all times? Also in your HTML code, which part do you want to be non-scrollable?

Comment: the ion-card floats above all scrolleable content